# ¿Como puedo cerrar la consola CMD mediante java?

Tags: java, java-8

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class CerrarConsola{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner datoIngresado = new Scanner(System.in), datoIngresadoDos = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    int edad =0;
    String nombre = "", comidaFavorita = "";

    System.out.println("Bienvenido..");
    System.out.println("\nCual es tu nombre...");
    System.out.print(">>>");
    nombre = datoIngresado.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nCual es tu edad...");
    System.out.print(">>>");
    edad = datoIngresado.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nCual es tu comida favorita...");
    System.out.print(">>>");
    comidaFavorita = datoIngresadoDos.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nSu nombre es: "+ nombre +"\nSu edad es: "+ edad + "\nSu comida favorita: "+ comidaFavorita);
    try{
      new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "pause").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    }catch(Exception e){
      /*nada*/
    }
  }
}
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que después de darle enter para continuar, se cierre la consola?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando corres tu programa hecho en Java realmente no estás corriendo únicamente tu programa.... los programas hechos en Java no tienen capacidad de hacer muchas cosas por algo llamado sandbox, ese sandbox es provisto por la máquina virtual que se encarga de ejecutar tu código y tal vez ya lo habías oido pero no pensado en lo que significa.

Significa que tus programas en Java, si bien se compilan para generar un binario, pero se trata de un binario que se ejecuta en un programa llamado java y que es la estrella de tu JRE.

Así que como cualquier comando que corras en windows en tu CMD puedes hacer que corra otro comando agregándole un `&&`.

por ejemplo si pruebas con tu block de notas puedes lograr el efecto que deseas mediante

```
notepad && exit
```

de igual manera puedes hacerlo con tus programas de Java

```
java --jar C:/miJar/mijar.jar && exit
```

Comment: es cierto gracias xD no me habia dado cuenta

Answer (score 0):

!Buenas!

Prueba con esto:

```
try{

  new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "pause").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
  System.exit(0);


}catch(Exception e){
  /*maneja tus errores aquí*/
}
```

El `System.exit(0)` cierra los procesos y debe de cerrar la consola. Deberia de ir donde te lo he puesto, tengo problemas con mi ordenador ahora mismo y no puedo probarlo en consola, solo en la de Eclipse.

Comment: no es buena práctica un catch vacío, ya que obviamente silencia cualquier error que pudiuera darse

Comment: Si bueno, el usuario ha preguntado el como cerrar la consola y me he ceñido en eso. Los errores que quiera controlar, ya ahí no puedo meterme sin saber que quiere realizar...

Comment: entonces en vez de `/*nada*/` deberías de ponerle `/*maneja tus errores aquí*/`

Comment: Si, quedaría mejor. Editado, gracias

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no cierra la consola. intente usar
try{
newProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","exit").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
}catch(Exception e){
      /*nada*/
    }

pero tampoco funciona. Se que deja el Exception vacío es mala costumbre pero solo es un programa de ejemplo.